# What's the max size of a BigTextStyle notification

Tags: android, android-wear-notification

I have a messaging app integrated with **Android Wear**. Similar to **Hangouts**, when selecting a notification in an Android Wear Smartwatch, you can swipe to the second card which displays the conversation corresponding to the selected message. I implement it with a `BigTextStyle` notification, but I need to know the max number of chars `BigTextStyle` supports so I can trim properly the conversation when it's too large to completely fit. I couldn't find this info on documentation.

After some investigation, max chars are about 5000, at least in an Android Wear emulator. Therefore, I can do something like:

```
// scroll to the bottom of the notification card
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setStartScrollBottom(true);

// get conversation messages in a big single text
CharSequence text = getConversationText();

// trim text to its last 5000 chars
int start = Math.max(0, text.length() - 5000);
text = text.subSequence(start, text.length());

// set text into the big text style
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text);

// build notification
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setStyle(style).extend(extender).build();
```

Does anyone know the exact number of characters that fit into a `BigTextStyle` notification? Does it changes between different devices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer**
The limit is 5120 characters (5KB) but you don't need to limit your messages. This is done for you on the builder.

**Detailed Answer**

On your code you are using `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` that internally uses `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

This is what happens When you call to `setBigContentTitle`

```
    /**
     * Overrides ContentTitle in the big form of the template.
     * This defaults to the value passed to setContentTitle().
     */
    public BigTextStyle setBigContentTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mBigContentTitle = Builder.limitCharSequenceLength(title);
        return this;
    }
```

The function [`limitCharSequenceLength`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/d732fd4f367018165b3881284cf588af9a86fbcf/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.java#L1755-L1762) do this

```
    protected static CharSequence limitCharSequenceLength(CharSequence cs) {
        if (cs == null) return cs;
        if (cs.length() > MAX_CHARSEQUENCE_LENGTH) {
            cs = cs.subSequence(0, MAX_CHARSEQUENCE_LENGTH);
        }
        return cs;
    }
```

And if we inspect the constant declaration we found this

```
    /**
     * Maximum length of CharSequences accepted by Builder and friends.
     *
     * <p>
     * Avoids spamming the system with overly large strings such as full e-mails.
     */
    private static final int MAX_CHARSEQUENCE_LENGTH = 5 * 1024;
```

Comment: I know the builder automatically limits the message, it's just that I needed to append some more text at the beginning of the message but at the same time, include as much text of the original message as I could. So I needed to know the limit. And there's probably better ways to do that than using a `BigTextStyle` notification. Anyways, thanks so much for your accurate answer.

Comment: Check that in the answer is the limit. Check the code of the function limitCharSequenceLength(CharSequence cs) and the value of the variable MAX_CHARSEQUENCE_LENGTH. Before you set the text to the builder you can do the same check and add at the beginning what you need